# How to translate text from one language to another in PHP?

Tags: php, translation, language-translation

I have a web-based chat application that allows me to talk to visitors on my website.

However, when chatting with a foreigner, I need to convert what they are saying into English so I can understand it. I then need to convert my English phrases into their language so they can understand the response. The most common languages I have dealt with are Spanish, Portuguese, and French.

I currently do this in Google Translate, by copying and pasting the text. I understand that automating that is against the terms of service, and doing it manually takes up a considerable amount of time.

I envision that this type of type of problem would be common in a lot of applications.

Is there any free solution that would allow me to do something like this? This is for personal use so I obviously don't have a large budget.

Comment: Google translate has an API so you can definitely automate what you're describing https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs note: I am aware it's paid but for small amounts of text it's really not that bad